# Javascript download string

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript tracking code:

```
function jTTrackPage() {
    if (jTPage == "") jTPage = escape(window.location);
    jTUrl = jTProtocol + "//" + jTGateway + "/jtrack.ashx?u=" + jTSession + "&d=" + jTDomain;
    jTUrl += "&p='" + jTPage + "'&r='" + escape(document.referrer) + "'";
    jTImage.src = jTUrl;
}
```

I works fine for tracking, however instead of returning an image I want my jtrack.ashx handler to return a string (a unique phone number), which my JS can then use to overwrite the generic number on my site, e.g.

```
<span class="number">generic number</span>
```

How can I do that, bearing in mind my tracking url is a different domain to the website.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at doing an ajax request of type text/plain, and simply store the response in a variable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started is a pretty good resource for doing asynchronous requests. Note that you typically need to have the website requesting to the same domain in order for this to work. Though you can get around this by using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS